# bluetooth pairing-dialog does not show up;

Tags: android, bluetooth, notifications, android-dialog, pairing

I am currently working on a bluetooth application and I am able to connect to paired and unpaired devices already but if i try to connect to a unpaired device the pairing dialog does not show up directly but there will be a notification in the background.

Is there a possibility to directly show the pairing-dialog?